Upload Flask app on shared hosting cpanel
Hello i'm trying to host my flask application on cpanel at shared hsoting. I have upload project and when i access my domain it shows directory files even there is .htaccess file in main directory. here is my .htaccess:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect all requests to Flask app
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.py/$1 [L]

i have app.py where functions are defined. Is there need to run this command through terminal: python3 app.py ?
i have no option "Setup python Application" in my cpanel. please help to host my flask app online.
Flask App Directory:


this might help. Why doesn't my server have "Setup Python App"?
